# Understanding how CSS clear:both is supposed to work

Tags: css, css-float

I have an HTML form based questionnaire I am trying to put together. I had lined up all the HTML form elements using CCS when I came across a problem floating elements.

I have a DIV containing some form elements that I wanted to place underneath the previous DIV. Since the previous DIV was "floated" to the left I figured I had to use the CSS syntax **clear:both**. However, when I did that my content went all the way over to the left of the page jumping out of it's containing DIV. I am not sure why.

I have created a JSFiddle example to help explain ...

http://jsfiddle.net/BrWUE/

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong and why the **clear:both** is pushing my DIV out of all it's containers? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how CSS clearing is supposed to work.
The clearing element will go underneath any prior sibling floated elements.

You should use one the numerous cleafix methods out there.
Here's one from the [html5boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/):

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1 }
```

And here's what it looks like on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/BrWUE/1/ .

Comment: What should I do if I only want to clear one floated DIV and not all of them?

Comment: Well it certainly looks like you fixed the problem (Thanks!) but I am at a loss for how it works. I have never seen the  syntax :before or :after in CSS.